# 3D rotation from a given normalized direction vector?

Tags: math, trigonometry

Whats the simplest way to calculate the rotation angles (alpha.x,beta.y,gamma.z) from a given normalized direction vector (x,y,z)?

I seem to have forgotten high school maths :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alpha.x = arccos(x)
beta.y  = arccos(y)
gamma.z = arccos(z)
```

This assumes `alpha.x` is the angle from the +x axis, beta.y with +y, gamma.z with +z.

This is derived simply from the dot product formula:

```
(x,y,z) * (1,0,0) = cos(alpha.x)
```

from which the first formula follows. Same with 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was assuming radians when the method was in degrees :)